# How can I resolve this issue in android studio?

Tags: android

Trying to build a basic application with a button in it and printing a message when the button is pressed.When I wrote the log method the attributes 'tag' and 'msg' saying cannot resolve symbol?I've done gradle sync and Invalidate caches/restart but still nothing is resolved.

This is the my code:

```
package com.example.exampleapp;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void clickFunction(View view){

        Log.i(tag:"Info" , msg:"Button Clicked")//Issue is at this line tag,msg cannot be resolved.
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just remove "tag:" and "msg:".

Answer (score 2):

Named parameters are not supported in `Java` So remove the `tag:` and `msg:` modifiers

like this

```java
public void clickFunction(View view){
   Log.i("Info" , "Button Clicked");
}
```

and don't forget to add the semicolon `;` at the end